# Android Seekbar two way data binding

Tags: android, data-binding

I try to implement a two way databinding for a seekbar. I know that i cound use `android:onProgressChanged` but wonder why i cant simply use `android:progress`.

If i understand correctly `@{}` is just for reading values and `@={}` is to read and write.
But if i set `android:progress="@={viewModel.value}` i get a bindingerror (error: cannot find symbol).

Is it not possible to use `@={}` and i have to use `android:onProgressChanged` or is there something else i have to do ?

Comment: There is an additional ' (apostrophe) in your code which might cause problems

Comment: no. it was just a typo here at stackoverflow